# Ошибка при создании файла

Tags: sql-server

Ку, пытаюсь создать текстовый файл через подобную команду

```
DECLARE @Text AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Cmd AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @Text = 'Hello world'
SET @Cmd ='echo ' +  @Text + ' > C:\AppTextFile.txt'
EXECUTE Master.dbo.xp_CmdShell  @Cmd
```

но получаю ошибку "Отказано в доступе" и null, 
а если пишу

```
declare @cmd varchar(1000)
declare @filepath varchar(500) = 'c:\samplefile.txt'
SET @cmd = 'bcp "select 1 as test" queryout "' + @filepath + '" -c -UTF8 -T -Slocalhost'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

получаю

```
output
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Не удается открыть файл данных BCP на сервере.
NULL
```

подскажите с чем это связанно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это связано с тем, что для создания файла в корне диска нужны соответствующие привилегии.

Comment: а где данные привилегии настраиваются?

Comment: @DimaAndrianov Вам надо не добавлять привилегий, а создавать файл в месте, которое для этого предназначено - например, `AppData\Local`.

Comment: А как найти такое место?

Comment: Сделал так ка указано в инструкции и все заработало https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @DimaAndrianov Молодец. Успехов!